# Non-cyclical PlotStyle?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to plot a Table of functions. Since the number of elements is unspecified, I want to specify a "repeating" graphic directive.

Supposing I have two direcives, *m* and *s*, I would like to do something like:

```
PlotStyle -> {m, s...}
```

But I can only specify

```
PlotStyle -> {m, s}
```

However, since this specification is cyclical, I get (what would be like)

```
{m, s, m, s, m, s...}
```

So I'm forced to specify

```
PlotStyle -> {m, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s, s}
```

for the exact number of elements in the Table, and breaking the graphical presentation for another number of elements.

Is there a way I can specify a directive for a number *n* of first elements in the Table, and another for the remaining elements?

Comment: One way to at least make the solution you have more manageable (ie, less code) would be something like `PlotStyle -> Flatten[{m, Table[s, 10]}` where `10` is the number of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual approach would be to programmatically generate the set of styles:

```
fns = x^Range[5];

Plot[fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Prepend[Table[Black, 4], Red]]
```

You could also use `Style` to override the setting coming from PlotStyle:

```
Plot[Evaluate[MapAt[Style[#, Red] &, fns, 1]], {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image]

Comment: Or `Show[
 Plot[First@fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 Plot[Rest@fns, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's a good way, except that the `PlotRange` will be determined by the first function.  Adding `PlotRange -> All` may help, but not if a function has a very large range compared to others.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - or the `PlotRange` can be specified as an option to `Show`

Comment: @BobHanlon Yeah, I meant adding `PlotRange -> All` to `Show[]` but didn't say where it was to go.

Comment: One could also use `PadRight[]`: `Plot[x^Range[5] // Evaluate, {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> PadRight[{Red}, 5, Black]]`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way with an `UpValue`:

```
repPlotStyle /: Plot[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, o1___,
   repPlotStyle[PlotStyle -> {s1 : Except[_List] ..., s2_List}],
   o2___] :=
  With[{n = Length[Block[{x = (a + b)/2.}, f]]},  (* could use Length[f] *)
   With[{s = Take[
        Join[{s1}, Apply[Join, Table[s2, {(n/ Length[s2]) + 1}]]],
        n]},
    Plot[f, {x, a, b}, o1, PlotStyle -> s, o2]
    ]];

Plot[Evaluate[ChebyshevT[Range@11, x]], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black}} // repPlotStyle]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[ChebyshevT[Range@11, x]], {x, -1, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, {Black, Blue, Green}} // repPlotStyle]
```

[image]

Or tweak an internal function in the same way (not guaranteed to work in versions other than 11.3):

```
Internal`InheritedBlock[
 {Charting`padList},
 Unprotect@Charting`padList;
 Charting`padList[{a_, b_List}, n_Integer] := Take[
    Prepend[Apply[Join, Table[b, {(n/ Length[b]) + 1}]], a],
    n];
 Protect@Charting`padList;
 Plot[Evaluate[ChebyshevT[Range@5, x]], {x, -1, 1},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, {Black}}]
 ]
(* same output as the first graphics *)
```